# Prove 2 formulas equivalent under some conditions?

Tags: z3, z3py

Two formulas `a1 == a + b` and `a1 == b` are equivalent if `a == 0`. I want to find this required condition (`a == 0`) with Z3 python. I wrote the code below:

```
from z3 import *

def equivalence(F, G):
    s = Solver()
    s.add(Not(F == G))
    r = s.check()
    if r == unsat:
        print 'Equ'
        print s.model()
    else:
        print 'Not Equ'

a, b = BitVecs('a b', 32)

g = True
tmp = BitVec('tmp', 32)
g = And(g, tmp == a)
tmp1 = BitVec('tmp1', 32)
g = And(g, tmp1 == b)
tmp2 = BitVec('tmp2', 32)
g = And(g, tmp2 == (tmp1 + tmp))
a1 = BitVec('a1', 32) 
g = And(g, a1 == tmp2)

f = True
f = And(f, a1 == b)

equivalence(Exists([a], g), f)
```

However, the above code always returns `"Not Equ"` as the output. Then obviously I cannot get the model (`a === 0`) as the condition for `"f"` and `"g"` to be equivalent, either.

Any idea on where the code is wrong, and how to fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps the following version solves what you want: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/75E9

Comment: Nikolaj, this does not really do what I want, since I want to find the "Assumption" in your solution as well. In my code, you can see that I print out the model to find out the value of "a" that can make "f" and "g" equivalent. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code in the post does not correspond to the question that is asked. 
A similar question was asked and answered on the smt-lib mailing list.